# Compiled c# file not opening when double clicked

Tags: c#, compilation

I compile my .cs file to .exe in cmd and it works fine and i can run it.
But when i open it by double clicking it opens cmd for a split second then closes, how can i make it actually work?
I tried to find solutions but didnt find any

Comment: Have you tried a **Console.ReadLine()** call at the end of your program ? It will keep the Command window up until the user presses [ENTER].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application closes when it reaches it's end.
Let's take this as an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

After printing `Hello world!` there is nothing left to execute so it closes. It work's from cmd because after the program closes, it exits back to cmd and you can still see what your program did. If you want keep your program open you have to stop it from reaching the end of `Main` (in this case). You can do this by waiting for the user to press enter with `Console.ReadLine()`, this way the application will only exit after the user pressed enter.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you want to keep it open until it's closed you can try freezing the main thread with `Thread.Sleep(-1)`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        Thread.Sleep(-1);
    }
}
```

For this you need to have `using System.Threading;` at the top.